# How to avoid showString error after dataframe groupBy

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `dataframe` in the following schema, that I extract from a Hive table using the SQL below:

| Id | Group_name | Sub_group_number | Year_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 1 | 202110 |
| 2 | Active | 3 | 202110 |
| 3 | Inactive | 4 | 202110 |
| 4 | Active | 1 | 202110 |

The T-SQL to extract the information is:

```
SELECT Id, Group_Name, Sub_group_number, Year_Month
FROM table
WHERE Year_Month = 202110
AND id IN (SELECT Id FROM table WHERE Year_Month = 202109 AND Sub_group_number = 1)
```

After extract this information I want to group by Sub_group to extract the Id quantity as below:

```
df = (df.withColumn('FROM', F.lit(1))
        .groupBy('Year_Month', 'FROM', 'Sub_group_number')
        .count())
```

The result is a table as below:

| Year_Month | From | Sub_group_number | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202110 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 202110 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 202110 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

Until this point there is no issue on my code and I'm able to run and execute action commands with Spark. The issue happens when I try to make the year_month and sub_group as parameters of my T-SQL in order to have a complete table. I'm using the following code:

```
sub_groups = [i for i in range(22)]
year_months = [202101, 202102, 202103]
for month in year_months:
    for group in sub_groups:
        query = f"""SELECT Id, Group_Name, Sub_group_number, Year_Month
                    FROM table
                    WHERE Year_Month = {month + 1}
                    AND id IN (SELECT Id FROM table WHERE Year_Month = {month} AND Sub_group_number = {group})"""
        df_temp = (spark.sql(query)
                        .withColumn('FROM', F.lit(group))
                        .groupBy('Year_Month', 'FROM', 'Sub_group_number')
                        .count())
        df = df.union(df_temp).dropDuplicates()
```

When I execute a `df.show()` or try to write as Table I have the issue:

> An error occurred while calling o8522.showString

[image: Full error trace]

Any ideas of what is causing this error?

Comment: There's a right square parenthesis missing : `sub_groups = [i for i in range(22)`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting *string interpolation*.

If using Python, maybe try this:

```
query = "SELECT Id, Group_Name, Sub_group_number, Year_Month
                    FROM table
                    WHERE Year_Month = {0}
                    AND id IN (SELECT Id FROM table WHERE Year_Month = {1} 
                    AND Sub_group_number = {2})".format(month + 1, month, group)
```

Comment: Now the error changed to o21583.showString

Answer (score 0):

The error states it is StackOverflowError that can happen when DAG plan grows too much. Because of Spark's lazy evaluation, this could easily happen with for-loops, especially you have nested for-loop. If you are curious, you can try `df.explain()` where you did `df.show()`, you should see pretty long physical plans that Spark cannot handle to run in actual.

To solve this, you want to avoid for-loop as much as possible and in your case , it seems you don't need it.

```py
sub_groups = [i for i in range(22)]
year_months = [202101, 202102, 202103]

# Modify this to use datetime lib for more robustness (ex: handle 202112 -> 202201). 
month_plus = [x+1 for x in year_months]

def _to_str_elms(li):
    return str(li)[1:-1]

spark.sql("""
    SELECT Id, Group_Name, Sub_group_number, Year_Month
    FROM table
    WHERE Year_Month IN ({','.join(_to_str_elms(month_plus))})
        AND id IN (SELECT Id FROM table WHERE Year_Month IN ({','.join(_to_str_elms(month))}) AND Sub_group_number IN ({','.join(_to_str_elms(sub_groups))}))
""")
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I understood why you are looping. You need "parent" group where along with the `Sub_group_number` of its record and you are using `lit` with looped value. I think one way is that you can rethink about this problem by first query to fetch all records that are in [202101, 202102, 202103, 202104], then use some window functions to figure out the parent group. I am not yet foreseeing how it looks like, so if you can give us some sample records and logic how you want to get the "group", I can perhaps provide updates.

Comment: I am not too confident of this sql but I am pretty sure you can use `IN` statement in replacement of the for-loops.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide records of data once its bank's property, but you are completely right! What I'm trying to do is understand quantity of people on each group that belongs to a group A (for example) in the previous month.

Comment: I don't need the real info.  I only need a list of Id, Year_Month, Sub_group_number with just the fake number like you have in question. If you have a list of this, can you show which `Sub_group_number` you need to have for `From` column of each record?